# How to return all database results row by row using Cursor - SQLite database *Working*

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Currently using an SQlite database with Android studio to build a login app. I am currently trying to retrieve the data from the database row by row and comparing the username and password to the input username and password of the user. Doing this I want to find the matching username and password and then output the corresponding user information.

I am unsure what the best method is for this. I have used a cursor but only seem to be able to return the first values in the database. Would it be best to use an ID column that autoincrements and compare a count value to the ID in a for loop? Or would it be better to output the entire database into an array and then use a count value on the main activity to  comb through the array for the necessary information.

Database code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BIOSECURE";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER";

public static final String COL_1 = "USERNAME";
public static final String COL_2 = "PASSWORD";
public static final String COL_3 = "FIRSTNAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "SECONDNAME";
public static final String COL_5 = "FINGERPRINT";
public static final String COL_6 = "FACE";
```

// Basic database

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USER ( USERNAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY, PASSWORD TEXT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, SECONDNAME TEXT, FINGERPRINT BLOB, FACE BLOB)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER");
}
// Inserting into database

public boolean insertUserData (String inputUsername, String inputPassword, String inputFirstName, String inputSecondName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_1, inputUsername);
    cv.put(COL_2, inputPassword);
    cv.put(COL_3, inputFirstName);
    cv.put(COL_4, inputSecondName);
    // contentValues.put(COL_5, inputFingerprint);
    // contentValues.put(COL_6, inputFace);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
    db.close();
    return result!= -1;
}

// Not working yet
public Cursor CompareUserData () {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    return cursor;
```

Main activity code:

```
                // CHECKING USER LOGIN DETAILS
            Cursor cursor = db.CompareUserData();
            for (count = 0; count<=cursor.getCount();count++)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToPosition(count))
                {
                    if (UsernameInput.getText().toString().equals(cursor.getString(0))&&PasswordInput.getText().toString().equals(cursor.getString(1)))
                    {
                     passUser = cursor.getString(0);
                     passPass = cursor.getString(1);
                     passFirst = cursor.getString(2);
                     passSecond = cursor.getString(3);

                     getUser();
                     getPass();
                     getFirst();
                     getSecond();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        LoginValidation();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count > cursor.getCount())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cursor is used to iterate over rows, but will only show one row at a time and must be moved to a different row, which is why it seems to just be showing the first row. You call `cursor.moveToFirst()`, but you never call any other `move*()` methods like `cursor.moveToNext()` or `cursor.moveToPosition()`.

That said, if you want to get the user that was provided by login from your database, getting all the records and iterating is really not the best way to do that. Your second query (`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id =`) is the right idea. If I understand your goals properly, you want to get one row back and then check the details against that one row. Database engines exist for the purpose of filtering data to return just what you want, don't duplicate its efforts here. Tell it what user `id` you want, and it will give you back the one user with that `id`.

Comment: I only added the ID to allow for loops of returning data. My aim is to compare my username and password input by the user to the database. if the username and password match records in the database it return all of that users information to individual variables for alter use.

Comment: In that case, just refer to the first part of my answer, which isn't complete, but points you in the right direction. You need to use the iterator provided to you with the cursor to advance through the result rows the cursor provides.

Comment: I solved the issue. Using a for count loop alongside cursor.movetoposition(count) did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to help others running into the same issue, you can always add your won answer and mark it as accepted with code examples showing what you did!

Comment: Once you post an answer there will be a checkmark icon near the upvote/downvote buttons. Click that to mark an answer as accepted.